# How to set a textview's background color to be holo green light via XML?

Tags: android

I've got a textview and I'd let to set its background color to be holo green light as mentioned [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html)

However, I can't figure out how to do this via XML.  Is it possible?  I currently have:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="200sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

However, I'm unable to change android:background to somehow reference holo green light.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I've tried "@android:color/" but no dice.

Comment: The textview background color is displaying for whole screen .Could you please tell me how to set background color for only one line of the textview. For example (Today )is a textview i want green color background for only the textview (TOday).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Via Java:

```
TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
test.setBackgroundResource(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
```

Via XML:

```
 <TextView
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="200sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:style="@style/textviewStyle" 
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml) is the API page about this topic

Answer (score 7):

`android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"` seems to work for me.
Your target API version does include the Holo theme, right?

Answer (score 1):

adding a new info as well it may help someone , u can do this via java as well

```
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.the_color_you_defind_in_your_colors_._xml);
```